# Springs manipulating objects on a frictionless surface

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

I have tried for hours and cannot get close to answering this question, any help is appreciated.

Question: Charlie Brown (mass = 25kg) and his dog Snoopy (mass = 15kg) are on a frictionless horizontal ice surface, both free to slide. They are joined by an ideal spring of relaxed length 2.5m, with a force constant of 150N/m. Charlie Brown is initially at rest, but Lucy has just given Snoopy an impulsive kick (she hates that dog) so that he is moving directly away from Charlie Brown with a speed of 12m/s. At the point at which Snoopy starts moving, the spring starts stretching. What is the total length of the spring when Snoopy first comes to rest?

I am having a serious problem relating all these forces. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Garvan and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Use energy relationships.

Answer (score 1):

When you have trouble relating forces, forget about them. Use momentum and energy.They are much easier.

Since they are on ice, the friction can be neglected. Thus, after poor Snoopy is kicked, the momentum of the Charlie-Snoopy-spring system can not change since their is no external force and the spring applies internal force. Therefore, when Snoopy comes to rest, all his momentum has been transferred to Charlie. Given the data, you can now obtain Charlie's speed from momentum conservation.

Now, the total mechanical energy of the system is also conserved. You have Snoopy's initial energy and Charlie's final energy. Subtract them to get energy stored in the spring, which will give you its compression as you have the force constant.(Compression because Charlie will be moving towards Snoopy to conserve direction of momentum).There is your answer, if you are careful with the calculations.